# One variable histogram using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a variable that has following values

```
sce_list[[1]]$total_counts
1                       3794
2                       2133
3                       3482
4                       1522
5                       3385
6                       5495
```

I want to make a histogram out of this using ggplot

and what I am doing is:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(size=1:length(sce_list[[1]]), 
                     count=sce_list[[1]]$total_counts,
                     aes(x=count, y=size))
       ) +
       geom_histogram()
```

could anyone let me now, where I am going wrong and give me a solution.

Note: i applied the following as suggested in the comments

```
   for  (i in 1:length(paths)){

 ggplot((size=1:length(as.data.frame(sce_list[[i]]))), 
 count=as.data.frame(sce_list[[i]]$total_counts), 
aes(x=count, y=size)) + geom_histogram()}
```

The error that I get is:

```
    Quitting from lines 121-150 (tq.Rmd) 
Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
Calls: <Anonymous> ... ggplot -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame -> as.vector
Execution halted
```

Thank you

Comment: I guess that `ggplot(sce_list[[1]], aes(total_counts)) + geom_histogram()` should do what you want.

Comment: @PoGibas: thank you for your ccomment. I get following Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class SingleCellExperiment

Comment: By definition, a histogram only has one variable, there cannot be a y variable. Also when debugging try to simplify, do all that complex work outside of ggplot to determine if the problem is with that or with ggplot itself.

Comment: Or you might want to plot barplot for which you should use `ggplot(data.frame(size = seq_len(nrow(seq_len(nrow(sce_list[[1]])))), 
                  count = sce_list[[1]]$total_counts), 
       aes(size, count))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: Also providing the error message and reproducible code would be helpful to people trying to help you.

Comment: After fixing your code formatting I think you have a problem with placement of parentheses.    @PoGibas gave you the correct answer given that you didn't provide any information on what class sce_list[[1]] is.  The error message you got tells you what to do -- make sce_list[[1]] into a data frame using as.data.frame().

Comment: @Elin and PoGibas: please see the edits in the question. I did apply: ggplot((size=1:length(as.data.frame(sce_list[[i]])), count=as.data.frame(sce_list[[i]]$total_counts), aes(x=count, y=size))) + geom_histogram()

Comment: Create your data frame.  Then run ggplot.  I don't see any suggestion that you do a loop!

Comment: Also you still did not fix the misplaced close parenthesis.This is the kind of question that is frustrating because you haven't provided a reproducible example at all nor have you responded to any of the comments by trying the suggestions in the comments  or additional information. You still have not said what kind of data you are working with!  We are not supposed to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to illustrate what a reproducible example would be based on guesses about what you are doing.

Since you don't seem to have a names for the columns and are coercing to a data frame I assume that your data is not a data frame or tibble.  Since it seems to have two columns, it isn't a vector.  Therefore I assume it is a matrix with two columns.

When you are having a problem with a complex embedding like you are having you need to break it out into pieces to make sure each piece works.  Note how an answerer could copy and pasted the code below.

```
x <- matrix(1:6, c(3794, 2133,  3482,   1522,    3385, 5495), ncol=2)
sce_list <- list()
sce_list$total_counts <- x
```

Let's coerce that to a data frame and see what it looks like.

```
as.data.frame(sec_list$total_counts)

  V1   V2
1  1  794
2  2 2133
3  3 3482
4  4 1522
5  5 3385
6  6 5495
```

Okay so now we know that the variable names are V1 and V2. Since we are trying to make a minimal reproducible example we'll not change the names.

Now let's do the ggplot.

A histogram is a very specific kind of plot for continuous data.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(sce_list$total_counts), aes(V2)) + 
      geom_histogram()
```

However a histogram with 6 data points and no duplicates doesn't really make sense, so I'm thinking you may want the actual values plotted in which case you would want geom_col(). (Also because you called them counts)

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(sce_list$total_counts), 
          aes(x= V1,y=V2)) + 
      geom_col()
```

[image: Image of column plot]

But that's only a guess in that the needed information has not been provided.